# UrlHelper.Action method adds som strange characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have follwoing code to create dynamic ul and li

```
linkBuilder.Attributes.Add("href", urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));
```

but for some reason which I dont know, the urlHelper.Action method adds some strange characters in the begining of the url (for example "%E2%80%8C"). it happens only for some of my custom Controllers. the wrong url is %E2%80%8C/Article/Create any idea why?

Comment: You have to show what you are posting in the `routeValues` and your routes defined in Global.asax.cs for the controllers you are talking about.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I use the default route (MVC adds when you create a mvc 3 project in vs) and I post nul as routeValues.